# Diagonizable Matrix and finding a sum using it

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

[image]

Ok so for part one, I believe the matrix is diagonazible becuase the determinant is non-zero. From there I can find the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors. I got the Eigenvalues to be $-1$, $2$, and $2$. From there I can get the eigenvectors, but I thought that I needed to have $3$ seperate eigenvalues to be able to diagonalize a matrix. Is that true or is that for something else?

Then for part two, assuming I can create the eigenvectors needed, is this where I can use the theorem $S*D^{241}*S^{-1}$, where S is the matrix created from spanning the eigenvectors.

I apologize if my formatting isn't correct. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest that you write your problem instead of linking it

Comment: Maybe you can take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388037/diagonalize-the-matrix-a-or-explain-why-it-cant-be-diagonalized/1388043#1388043) to see when a matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: Matrix can be diagonalised if and only if it has distinct eigenvectors

Comment: "matrix is diagonazible becuase the determinant is non-zero" are you sure about this??

Comment: Am I sure the determinate is non-zero or that makes it diagonizable? I'm sure the determinate is non-zero, and I thought I saw somewhere that it made it diagonizable, but after looking at the link above, I don't believe it does anymore.

Comment: If matrix A has eigen-space matrix with  determinant zero than the matrix A can't be diagonalised.

Comment: @Basti whats wrong about identity matrix

Comment: You've got the correct eigenvalues; the eigenvector for $-1$ is dead easy to write down, and getting two LI eigenvectors for $2$ is dead easy, just do it. Then you've got $S$ and away you go, you've got the right idea.

Comment: Cool. Thanks...